# sum amounts from csv file to .txt

Tags: c#, linq

CSV data to .txt and sum all the amounts

```
string fileName = "../../TechFiles/";

using (var reader = new StreamReader(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConfigurationSource"]))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();

        var values = line.Split(',');

        string fullFileName = fileName + values[4] + ".txt";

        List<helper> package = new List<helper>
        {
            new helper() { bankName = values[4], amount = double.Parse(values[6])}
        };

        List<ResultLine> result = package.GroupBy(i => i.bankName)
                                         .SelectMany(cl => cl.Select(
                                             csLine => new ResultLine
                                             {
                                                 bankName = csLine.bankName,
                                                 Quantity = cl.Count().ToString(),
                                                 amount = cl.Sum(c => c.amount),
                                             }))
                                          .ToList<ResultLine>();

        List<string> listA = new List<string>();

        foreach (var book in result)
        {
            if (!listA.Contains(book.bankName))
            {
                listA.Add(book.bankName);

                File.WriteAllText(fullFileName,
                    book.bankName + " " + book.amount + " " + book.Quantity);

            }
        }
```

I put csv path on the app.config then retrieved all the data to the text file, but the problem is I want to some my `value[4]` which is a header and a sum of all the amounts to the header but it only returns a single amount, so I need a way to pass all the amounts same time so I can be able to sum the total.

Comment: Don't you just want the `GroupBy` bit outside of the loop through each line?

Comment: List<helper> package = new List<helper>
        {
            new helper() { bankName = values[4], amount = double.Parse(values[6])}
        }; this is where my problem lies as this retrieves one line instead all the lines so it doensnt sum them

Answer (score 0):

You'll either need to loop through all the values twice (once to calculate the sum and once to write the text file), or sum the values as you write them to the text file and then insert the header row to the text file after you have written all the details.

Comment: say i wanted to read this data from a csv file.  List<helper> package = new List<helper>
                    {
                        

                        new helper() { bankName = "look" , amount = 6},
                        new helper() { bankName = "fool" , amount = 8},
                        new helper() { bankName = "cool", amount = 8},
                        new helper() { bankName = "fool", amount = 2},
                        new helper() { bankName = "tech", amount = 12},
                        new helper() { bankName = "tech", amount = 2},
                    };

Comment: cause i used fetched the data with this one and it doesnt sum cause it pulls records one at a time  List<helper> package = new List<helper> { new helper() { bankName = values[4], amount = double.Parse(values[6])} };

Comment: You seem a little lost here... where would you expect that to pull a list from? That statement does not fetch data, it just instantiates one of your helper classes and throws it in a List that will have exactly one entry.

Comment: var line = reader.ReadLine();

This is where you're fetching data - one line at a time.

Comment: i fetch data from a csv file which the directory i stored in the app.config and    i need to fetch my data there then Sum my data grouping with bankName storing to different file

Comment: Well, no one here is going to do your assignment for you... you don't seem to understand the code you've written. You are reading one row of data into a brand new list object every time you iterate through your while loop. The way your code is written, there is never any way "package" will contain more than a single row of data. Once you understand that you should be able to fix your own problem.

Comment: thanks for all the help i solved my problem, i now understand what i was doing wrong